# Colon Separated Value Regular Expression Validation

Tags: java, regex

I admittedly am not a Regular Expression expert, but would like to validate an input string and writing if/else statements for various validations just isn't the way to do this.  I'm using Java.

The input will be in the form a colon (:) separated tuple of three values.  The first value will be an integer (potentially a long in terms of size/length), with the other two values being either numberic or a string.

For example, the following values would be valid:

- 1:x:456
- 2:2:3
- 3:abc:123

..and these would not:

- x:1:2
- 1::2
- 1:3::x
- 1:2
- fyz::2:1
- 1:3::3

Is there a relatively easy way to validate this input using a regular expression?

Comment: For the 2nd and 3rd parts, are they *either* text or numbers? That is, no mixing.

Comment: Either can be either.  Completely independent.

Comment: Can the colon separator be used as a literal in the string? For example: `42:"Ratio of fuel:oil is 30:1":xyz`?

Comment: Nope.  No quotes, no whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Matching `Numbers:(letters OR numbers):(letters OR numbers)`

If you want it such that it has to be numbers or letters only for 2nd and 3rd part, you can use this pattern:

```
String pattern = "^\\d+(:([A-Za-z]+|\\d+)){2}$";
```

Basically it will look for a sequence of numbers (`\\d+`), followed by a twice-repeated sequence of characters:

- starting with a a `:`, followed by

  - a sequence of letters (English), that is `[A-Za-z]`, OR
  - a sequence of numbers

The `^` and `$` characters are anchors, meaning "beginning-of-string" and "end-of-string"

Example:

```
public class RegexTest {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "^\\d+(:([A-Za-z]+|\\d+)){2}$";
        String example = "333:abc:123456";
        if (example.matches(pattern)) {
           System.out.println("Matches");
        }   
    }
}
```

### Matching `Numbers:(both letters and numbers:(both letters and numbers)`

For this, you can use this pattern:

```
String pattern = "^\\d+(:[A-Za-z0-9]+){2}$";
```

Which will match:

- A series of digits, followed by
- A colon, followed by any combination of letters or numbers

  - repeat this sequence twice

---

```
   public class RegexTest {
        public static void Main(String[] args) {
            String pattern = "^\\d+(:[A-Za-z0-9]+){2}$";
            String example = "333:a3b4c:12adf3456";
            if (example.matches(pattern)) {
               System.out.println("Matches");
            }   
        }
    }
```

This example will match.

Answer (score 1):

For the case where the 2nd and 3rd values can be mixed:

```
/^[0-9]+:[0-9a-zA-Z]+:[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
```

For the case where they can be only a string or only a number:

```
/^[0-9]+:([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+):([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

```
 ^[0-9]+:[^:]+:[^:]+
```

Start of line, followed by digits, followed by colon followed by any number of non-colon characters, followed by a  colon followed by non-colon characters.

This should be the most flexible colon delimited format that starts with digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /\d+:\[a-zA-Z0-9]+:\[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
```

if you knew the max lengths you could do

```
    /\d{1,X}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,Y}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,Z}/
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings may contain colons inside quoted strings, like this:

```
1234:"Ratio is 1:20":"Fuel:Oil"
```

Then you need to work around the colons inside the string. Building on Barton Chittenden's answer, you could use this:

```
^(\d+):(".+?"|[^"][^:]*):(".+?"|[^"][^:]*)$
```

[See it on regexr](http://regexr.com?30p43). It breaks down for silly things like `123:":"`, but you could modify the regex to handle these edge cases too.